# Jquery: ColorBox Not Working

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am trying to implement jquery plugin Colorbox.
Using collorbox I want another HTML page to open in the colorbox window. But it is not working.
Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script>


$("#text1").colorbox({href:"hello.html" width:500, height:500});        

</script>
```

And here is the HTML code.

```
<div id='container'>
<div id="sign1" class="sign" style="background-image:url('images/log.jpg'); position:absolute; width:1440px; height:25px;">
</div>
<div id='text11' class='text'><font color='white'><a id='text1' href="hello.html"> Sign Up </div></font>
</div>
```

How do I get hello.html to open up in the colorbox window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution, iframe is an attribute which needs to be used.

```
$(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
```